# Comment enseigner le français à ceux qui le connaissent déjà un peu ?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, oral, apprentissage

Une amie de 25 ans m'a demandé de lui enseigner le français.
Je suis prof, mais pas de langues; j'enseigne le dessin d'animation.

Cela dit, je dévore tous les ouvrages ayant rapport à la pédagogie, et ma maîtrise du français est, je l'espère, assez solide pour donner un cours, au moins jusqu'à un certain niveau (même si, n'ayant pas pratiqué depuis des années, mon français est un peu rouillé, surtout à l'écrit).

Mon problème:
Si je dois donner un cours à quelqu'un qui n'a aucune idée de la langue française, ou à des enfants, je pense pouvoir m'en sortir.
Mais la personne en question peut lire et écrire en français (avec moins de fautes que beaucoup de Français de souche). Il lui manque principalement:

- Du vocabulaire
- La facilité (manipulation facile et rapide du français, sans réfléchir)
- L'élocution
- Un usage correct des temps et des pronoms

Et là, j'ai un peu du mal à savoir comment procéder. J'ai un peu peur de ne pas être utile, mais surtout j'ai peur de mal enseigner (inscrire de mauvais réflexes).

Pour résoudre chacun des problèmes, j'ai pensé à ça:

- Vocabulaire: Lui donner de la lecture (type livres d'enfants agréables à lire par des adultes, comme « cabot-caboche » de Daniel Pennac), puis lui demander d'écrire des résumés; aussi, à chaque nouveau mot, faire un brin d'étymologie afin d'ouvrir la compréhension à d'autres futurs nouveaux mots éventuels.
- La facilité: Simulation de conversations, sur différents sujets
- L'élocution: Lecture à voix haute, où l'exercice est de me faire « entendre », par l'intonation, les sujets, les verbes, les virgules, etc. Cela l'obligera à détacher les mots distinctement et à se concentrer sur le sens.
- Un usage correct des temps et des pronoms: exercices de conjugaison, en insistant sur le sens des différents temps et leur relation entre eux. Je me concentre beaucoup sur les noms des temps (par exemple: imparfait = action dans le temps mais sans fin définie, donc « imparfaite », plus que parfait = imparfait + finalité donc « plus que parfaite »…). Je n'ai jamais rien lu sur ces relations, elles me viennent naturellement (je ne sais même pas si elle sont reconnues ou si c'est tout dans ma tête), donc s'il y a un ouvrage qui les relate, j'aimerai bien le consulter. Je ne lui donne que les temps les plus en usage dans la langue moderne (donc, pas de subjonctif imparfait, par exemple).
- A part ça, pendant toute la durée du cours (2h, une fois par semaine), il est interdit de prononcer un seul mot dans une autre langue que le français.

Mes questions:

- Est-ce que quelqu'un s'est déjà retrouvé dans cette situation, et si oui, y a-t-il quelque chose que vous pouvez m'apprendre (que vous ayez été le prof ou l'étudiant) ?
- Est-ce quelqu'un ici enseigne le français professionnellement? Si oui, pourrait-il/elle me donner des indications ?
- Mais surtout: Qu'est-ce que vous en pensez ?

La personne en question (ainsi que moi-même) est Libanaise (au cas où cela peut influer sur la méthode d'apprentissage).
Merci d'avance pour toute réponse ou suggestion.

PS: Si vous avez des suggestions de livres simples, mais pas infantiles, je suis preneur.

Comment: Je me rends compte que la question est subjective au moment de déterminer la bonne réponse...Elles sont aussi valables l'une que l'autre. Je vais attendre un peu d'appliquer puis revenir commenter et selectionner la réponse qui m'a le plus aidé.

Comment: au final, les réponses les plus utiles m'ont été données par mon étudiante IRL et un autre étudiant. Morale: toujours écouter ses élèves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Je suis dans la situation inverse, celle de l'étudiant, et voici quelques remarques et retours d'expérience que je peux faire.

Dans tous les cas, pour apprendre, les techniques de [Spaced Repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) sont les meilleures. Elles peuvent très bien être faites avec des fiches en carton.

### Lire un roman : Facilité, Temps et pronoms

Je ne pense pas que lire un roman seul, puis de faire un résumé soit la bonne façon d'acquérir du vocabulaire. Si on bloque sur trop de mots, la lecture devient rébarbative, et il n'y a plus aucun plaisir, et on finit par abandonner. 
Si on bloque sur peu de mots, on aura le sens général, et il faut vraiment être très motivé pour prendre la peine de sortir un dictionnaire. 
A ce titre, les e-books qui ont des dictionnaires intégrés peuvent changer la donne.

En revanche, la lecture permet d'acquérir une certaine facilité d'utilisation de la langue, d'assimiler les usages des temps et des pronoms.

Quelques suggestions de lecture (romans ou BD que j'aime, dans un français moderne mais correct, et une orientation « adolescent » qui laisse le vocabulaire accessible) :

- *Asterix et Obélix*, BD de Goscinny & Uderzo (il y a souvent des jeux de mots)
- *Trolls de Troy*, BD de Mourier & Guth
- *Exercice de Style*, Quéneau (la même histoire courte, racontée 99 fois, de 99 manières différentes)
- *La Fée Carabine*, Daniel Pennac
- *Le temps des miracles*, Anne-Laure Bondoux

### Lire les actualités : Prononciation, Facilité, Vocabulaire

L'étudiant lit un article d'actualité dans la langue étrangère, à haute voix.

Remarque : Au besoin, il lit un article similaire dans sa langue maternelle, pour se familiariser avec le sujet et ne pas être bloqué par le sens global.

Le professeur demande des synonymes des mots les plus complexes.

### Résumer et exprimer son opinion: Facilité, Prononciation

Ensuite, l'étudiant peut résumer l'article et exprimer son opinion.

Cela lui donnera confiance.

Mais ce n'est pas la technique la plus efficace pour apprendre, je pense. De fait, on ne peut qu'utiliser le vocabulaire que l'on connait déjà.

### Retranscrire une vidéo : Vocabulaire, Idiomes

L'étudiant regarde un documentaire ou écoute une chanson. Plus difficile: un sketch humoristique.

Il doit ensuite retranscrire les dialogues à l'écrit. Le professeur fournit un squelette dans lequel il manque les passages intéressants (vocabulaire nouveau, idiomes, nombres, ou tout autre chose que l'on souhaite travailler).

Quelques conseils :

- *Asterix et Cleopâtre* (autant le film que le film d'animation)
- *Cyrano de Bergerac* (avec du vieux français)
- *Le Dîner de cons* (beaucoup de jeux de mots, et le film est très drôle)
- *Le Père Noël est une ordure* (beaucoup de comique de situation, de nombreuses scènes ou expressions sont « cultes »)
- *La cité de la peur*
- *Le Déclin de l'empire américain* (avec un accent québécois)
- *Le fabuleux destin d'Amélie Poulain*
- *La Môme* (avec un accent parisien)
- *La Haine*
- *Les tontons flingueurs*

### Jeu du dictionnaire : Vocabulaire

Il y aussi un jeu que l'on joue à plusieurs et qui est très bien pour découvrir du vocabulaire : [le jeu du dictionnaire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_du_dictionnaire).

Comment: J'ai tenté des techniques classiques avec mon étudiante (jeux de rôles, etc), qui m'a avoué qu'elle se faisait ch*** à mort et qu'elle n'apprendrait jamais rien comme ça. Poignardant mon ego de prof, je lui ai demandé comment elle voudrait apprendre, et les méthodes qu'elle m'a conseillé sont exactement celles citées ici. Elle y est arrivée par intuition pure, mais votre réponse donne encore plus de poids à ses suggestions. Je vais tenter cette méthode.

Comment: Soit dit en passant, et à part, à la limite, l'expression "retour d'expérience", j'aurai cru parler à un Français. Bravo pour la maîtrise de la langue!

Comment: @Xananax oops pardon pour la fraude, je suis Français francophone, mais je continue d'apprendre l'anglais.

Comment: Ah zut j'ai l'air stupide maintenant :)

Answer (score 9):

Une [question à peu près similaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/492/are-there-good-tools-for-learning-to-speak-french) a déjà été posée.

Le site le [Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/) peut être utile.

Tu peux aussi te servir d'une méthode d'enseignement du FLE pour adultes

Comment: "Le Point du FLE" est **TRES** utile! Merci beaucoup pour cette source

Comment: *La question à peu près similaire* n'est pas très pratique pour un français (faible en anglais) qui veut apprendre à un non anglophone.

Answer (score 5):

Essayez de ne pas rester seuls, trouvez d'autres francophones avec qui discuter, dans une ambiance détendue. On ne le dira jamais assez, rien de tel que l'immersion pour apprendre une langue. Je salue d'ailleurs vos cours uniquement en français.

Si tu désires un livre pour enfants avec beaucoup de vocabulaire, je te recommande **[Histoire à toutes les sauces](http://gaetan.doremus.free.fr/spip.php?article6)**. Une histoire d'une page racontant comment un chat a tenté d'attraper un oiseau dans un parc et n'a pas réussi. Sur la page suivante (et toutes les autres, d'ailleurs) l'histoire est racontée à nouveau, mais dans une ambiance différente, avec d'autres mots, dans un thème différent. Impossible d'être bloqué par le manque de compréhension de l'histoire : c'est toujours la même !

Les livres, c'est une bon moyen d'enrichir le vocabulaire, mais si tu veux lui enseigner des tournures de phrases, ne néglige pas la télévision et le cinéma. Avec un DVD, c'est encore mieux : elle peut arrêter le film pour te poser des questions. Ce qui te manque, je pense, ce sont des cas précis à aborder, afin que les cours ne soient pas uniquement théoriques. Les personnages des films utiliseront des mots et des tournures que tu n'utilises pas beaucoup, ça serait dommage de ne lui apporter que le vocabulaire d'un seul francophone.

Comment: @Xananax Très important, si vous côtoyez d'autres francophones, il faut absolument qu'ils la corrigent lorsqu'elle fait des fautes. Gentiment, hein, on s'entend…

Comment: Il faut aussi, tant qu'à faire, choisir des francophones qui parlent bien…

Answer (score 3):

J'ai enseigné le français à ma femme de zéro, jusqu'à maintenant où elle parle couramment, en passant par le stade dont vous parlez. Je pense que la plupart des manuels enseignent un français qui est trop différent du français parlé pour pouvoir être utile.

La meilleure méthode que j'ai trouvée, c'est de regarder ensemble une série télé en français, et d'expliquer phrase par phrase ce que les gens disent, et de revenir en arrière jusqu'à ce qu'elle arrive à bien décomposer le son de chaque mot. Aussi de noter le vocabulaire nouveau.

Je trouve que comprendre les gens est le plus important. Quand on parle même si, au début, on fait des fautes, la communication passe. Et ensuite, à force d'entendre les gens parler, on arrête tout seul de faire des fautes. Mais, si on ne comprend pas ce que les gens disent, il n'y a aucun moyen de vraiment « échanger » avec un français.

Aussi, en regardant une série ou un film on voit beaucoup de vocabulaire très courant, mais peu enseigné, comme par exemple « Je viens de le faire », « Vu que », « plein de », « J'en peux plus », « Je t'ai eu », « Ça me va », « Ça se peut pas », « Ça se tente », « Ça me dirait bien de… », « Y a intérêt à… » etc.
Tous ces mots que les français répètent à longueur de journée, mais qu'on enseigne nulle part.
De plus, ça permet de s'habituer aux contractions et omissions usuelles que font les gens comme « T'as vu ça ? », « J'mange trop », « Faut le faire », « T'inquiète »,…

Enfin bref, j'espère que mon expérience peut vous aider un peu.

PS: Les séries doublées sont souvent plus faciles à comprendre…

Comment: Une bonne méthode que j'avais vue est la lecture sous titrée dans la langue visée (français + sous titres français)