# Where could I find "simple French novels"?

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources

When I was learning English, there were some “simple English novels”, for example, “Désirée's diary”, or “treasure island”, that is, some classic novels, was modified to a simpler version, with limited vocabulary, so that beginners could read and improve.

Are there such things for French?

There are some French novels I could find, but most are original ones, that is too difficult to me.

I hope could find some “Simple French novels” for reading, within, say, 1500 French vocabulary…

Comment: If you're looking for commercial books most of the international publishers that publish easy English readers also publish easy French readers graded by level; you can add to those [CLE International](http://www.cle-inter.com/) a French publishing house specialised in French as a foreign language.  If you want free stuff from the internet it will be more difficult to find. You could have a look at [Le Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/litterature.htm).

Comment: This Quebec site could be of some help as well : http://jean-nicolaslefle.viabloga.com/.

Comment: @Laure you should turn your comment in answer.

Comment: @chepseskaf: I did not want to make it an answer because I did not think it was very interesting as far as *French Language and usage* is concerned. I suppose my answer is an expert answer to the question but was the question appropriate for FL&U? I suppose it has been considered appropriate since it has been upvoted. What is the point of turning my comment  into an answer? Except gaining a few upvotes? Which of course should remain subsidiary.

Comment: @Laure maybe i can put it this way... learning french, is also possible to enjoy the beautiful of french language and french culture... for example i'm reading a book called "mon premier dictionnaire", i guess it was meant for 4 years old children, but whatever... i read and quite enjoy it.. here is a good one from this simple book: <<Admirable.>>

Il a neigé. Le paysage est d'une beauté étonnante, tout à fait admirable. Je peux rester des heures à l'admirer. Daniel ne comprend pas mon admiration. Lui, il n'a de regards admiratifs que pour les champions.

Comment: Rather than a copy/paste, I redirect you to a related question http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/comment-enseigner-le-francais-a-ceux-qui-le-connaissent-deja-un-peu/1577#1577

Comment: @rds thanks a lot, i just chose a book, but seems a bit overwhelming to me :p hope i can pass through...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer to this question is that you have to search for "livres faciles" or "romans faciles" even in the google. The keyword for your search is the word "facile". I searched it and I found many titles (or even many texts). You do it yourself.

Comment: Wow, even a [lmgtfy](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=lmgtfy&l=1) would be more useful as he'd actually end up with results. What did you find?

Comment: Actually carrying on the search, it seems more easy to search in English, for french people are not so interested in reading simple books in their own language anyway (so what's called *“simple”* can be a lot harder than imagined, or just childishly boring).

Answer (score 3):

In high school French class, we read Volkswagen Blues and Le Petit Prince. Im not sure what you mean by 1500 French level, but they would be good books to check out.

Comment: @le-garry thanks :)

Comment: “Knowing 1500 words of vocabulary” sort of represents a level in a language's knowledge.