# Fiction works for intermediate learners of French, similar to "Le petit prince"

Tags: ressources, littérature

I've been learning French for a while. *Le Petit Prince* is at just the right reading difficulty, and I thoroughly enjoyed it. Are there other books similar to this? I'm looking for a novel:

- Originally French
- Not simplified on purpose (like many simplifications of famous works)
- At a reading difficulty level approximately that of *Le Petit Prince*

I did read [this similar question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/where-could-i-find-simple-french-novels), which mentions *Volkswagen Blues*, but I can't seem to get hold of that book.

Comment: I'm glad you found the question I think this one is a duplicate of, and sadly, it's essentially unanswered, it's better answers being hidden in comments. There are more suggestions [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/comment-enseigner-le-francais-a-ceux-qui-le-connaissent-deja-un-peu/1577#1577). I hope this one gets better answers :·)

Comment: It may be a bit more difficult than *Le petit prince*, but I read `L'Etranger` (A. Camus) when I was younger, and found it really easy to read and quite interesting.

Answer (score 6):

If poetry is inside your search span, I'd suggest reading **Jacques Prévert**'s poems. No need to be an excellent french reader to read most of them. But it definitely needed a true genius to write them in the first place.

Now two examples to match Nikana's expectations (I'm kidding but you were right of course).

First, this one moment of sheer perfection and simplicity :

> Premier jour
>
> Des draps blancs dans une armoire
> Des draps rouges dans un lit
> Un enfant dans sa mère
> Sa mère dans les douleurs
> Le père dans le couloir
> Le couloir dans la maison
> La maison dans la ville
> La ville dans la nuit
> La mort dans un cri
> Et l'enfant dans la vie.

Or else, this one, that I find amazing too :

> Dimanche
>
> Entre les rangées d'arbres de l'avenue des Gobelins
> Une statue de marbre me conduit par la main
> Aujourd'hui c'est dimanche les cinémas sont pleins
> Les oiseaux dans les branches regardent les humains
> Et la statue m'embrasse mais personne ne nous voit
> Sauf un enfant aveugle qui nous montre du doigt.

The [wiki page](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9vert) and [this website](http://xtream.online.fr/Prevert/) may help you to discover the man and his writings further.

Comment: Examples, links, excerpts ? :·)

Comment: Yes, good idea. Some people may have access to this site but no access to wikipedia/google. Makes sense. ;-)

Comment: Roh, si je dis *morceaux choisis*, ça sonne plus comme si c'était toi qui avais la compétence pour nous le présenter, et moins comme si c'était moi qui avais la flemme ? ^^'

Comment: @Nikana Toi tu sais parler aux hommes de lettres ;-)

Comment: Dans les poètes, le québécois [Hector de Saint Denys Garneau](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hector_de_Saint-Denys_Garneau) présente lui aussi des textes très simples, bien que ça poésie soit moins "enfantine" que celle de Prévert. Mais, comme je suis dans un commentaire, je ne peux pas vous mettre d'extrait :-)

Comment: À la frontière de la poésie et de la prose, il y a la POESIE EN PROSE, avec [Aloysius Bertrand](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloysius_Bertrand) et Beaudelaire, qu'on ne présente plus je suppose. Voir extraits d'Aloysius [ICI](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Gaspard_de_la_nuit/%C3%89dition_1920) et le Beaudelaire [LÀ](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Petits_Po%C3%A8mes_en_prose). Certaines tournures sont un peu datées, l'ensemble est de la littérature "adulte", mais toutes les phrases restent belles et simples. Toujours pas d'extraits, bien sûr :-)

Comment: J'ai fait une énoOorme faute d'ortho. dans mon premier commentaire mais je ne peux pas l'éditer !? Qu'est-ce donc  qui se passe ??

Comment: Great tip and great poems. I didn't understand every word of them, but what's great about poems is that it's also very much a rythmic pleasure to read. So you can actually enjoy them even if you don't understand all the words.

Comment: @citizen I'm extremely happy to hear that. I could just hope that the simplicity and universality I felt in Prévert's writing really was that sharable. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

I would say that lot of children books are well written, simple to read yet enjoyable for adults. From illustrated books for the youngest to short novels. Comic books, if you are into it, might be interesting too.

Out of the blue, I would say you might enjoy « Les contes du chat perché » from Marcel Aymé. Of course, other « fairy tales » are good too, although Grimm's one are not natively French (but have classical translations). You still have the Charles Perrault tales... And works like « La Belle et la Bête ».

On a more contemporary side, I enjoyed « Verte » by Marie Desplechin, a modern sorceress story.

Answer (score 2):

In the "children's books that can also be enjoyed by adults" department, I would cite the stories of *Le Petit Nicolas* by Sempé and Goscinny, and also the books of Pierre Gripari (*Contes de la rue Broca* and similar stories).

Comment: +1 for *Le petit Nicolas*, I didn't think of it, but it seems to fit perfectly with asked material. And very fun to read, also. When *Le petit Prince* sometimes borders on melancholia and philosophy, *Le petit Nicolas* is much more light and upbeat, but is still intelligent and well written.

Answer (score 1):

You should also have a look at [the books which are actually used to teach French children](https://eduscol.education.fr/cid135424/lectures-a-l-ecole-des-listes-de-reference.html). "Le petite prince" is listed in there among many other books.

I would also suggest the *Fables* From *Jean de la Fontaine*: see [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/17941) and [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/17942).

Comment: *Jean de La Fontaine*'s fable contains a lot of words quite aging or sophisticated one's.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Eduscol list is no longer  available.

Comment: @IkWeetHetOokNiet It is available. I have updated the link.

Comment: Thanks for updating the link!

Comment: @IkWeetHetOokNiet You are welcome. "Le petit prince" is listed within the "Cycle 3" document. Thus, assuming you are looking for books of a similar level of difficulty, you should check this document rather than the other ones which are meant for younger children.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend “Les Contes du chat perché”, by Marcel Aymé.