# Alternative à KnoWord pour développer mon français

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there good tools for learning to speak French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/492/are-there-good-tools-for-learning-to-speak-french)

Je suis un étudiant et je veux apprendre de nouveaux mots. Quand j'apprends l'anglais, j'utilise http://knoword.org. Connaissez-vous un site similaire en français ?

Comment: Nous concentrons les demandes de ressources dans quelques questions générales, sauf requête extrêmement spécifique. Voir [Les demandes de ressources pour l'apprentissage du français sont-elles valables ?](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/127/are-resources-for-learning-french-on-topic-les-demandes-de-ressources-pour-lap) Donc je clos cette question comme doublon de la question générale sur les demandes d'apprentissage.

Comment: Je ne veux pas que mon question ressemble le question "Les demandes de ressources pour l'apprentissage du français sont-elles valables". Tu doit attendre a que autre est d'accorde avec tu. Je regrette mon pauvre français.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any french websites doing the same, but there is a very official French Language website where you can find many informations about french language, words, or anything related to it. For instance you can have a look at the "lexicographie" entry on the website, to pick a random word :

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/