# Oxford 3000 for French

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources, lexique

[“The Oxford 3000”](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/oxford3000/) ([PDF listing](http://englishforme.weebly.com/uploads/5/0/8/8/5088721/the_oxford_3000.pdf)) is a selection of the 3000 most frequently used words in English. If you know them, you can understand the meaning of more than 80% of the words in a general text.

Is there something like that for French? A simplified dictionary for students would be nice too. Because I'm in a condition in which I cannot buy any book, I would prefer to find such dictionary online or in PDF format so that I can print it.

Comment: maybe related to http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/492/are-there-good-tools-for-learning-to-speak-french

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know of any resource as complete as the Oxford 3000, but lists of words sorted by frequency have been compiled by lexicologists, such as:

- [one published on Éduscol](http://eduscol.education.fr/cid47916/liste-des-mots-classee-par-frequence-decroissante.html) (direct [PDF link](http://media.eduscol.education.fr/file/ecole/20/6/liste-mots-par-frequence_115206.pdf)), created by Étienne Brunet, has the most used 1500 words. It is commonly used by elementary or middle school teachers.
- Wiktionary has [another one](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire%3aListe_de_1750_mots_fran%C3%A7ais_les_plus_courants), with 1750 words all linked to the relevant Wiktionary page. Unfortunately, the link to the original source (*“Liste de 1750 mots connus d’un enfant de 4 ans, d’après l’académie d'Amiens”*) is dead.

Answer (score 2):

For 1000 words, featuring prepositions and such, I found this one, based on work by the [Lexique.org](http://www.lexique.org) team: [Lexique 1000](http://french.languagedaily.com/wordsandphrases/most-common-words)¹.

For 2000 words, there seem to be [very interesting flashcards](http://quizlet.com/10716652/the-2000-most-common-french-words-flash-cards/) to help learn them.

¹ Let's name it that.