# Some “step-by-step French reading” resource recommendations?

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oxford 3000 For French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/oxford-3000-for-french)

When I was in Alliance Française, there were some “step-by-step” book to build French vocabulary.

For example, one can choose some “500 words” books — each book is written using with-in 500 words. Then he can try 800, 1000, 1200 etc…

Where could I find such materials on-line?