# Any good list for most commonly used phrases and expressions?

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources

There are a lot of lists of words, which could be imported directly into Anki. For example, memrise has [an online course](http://www.memrise.com/course/131111/5000-most-common-french-words-2/), containing 5000 most frequent words in the French language. Now I nearly finish learning them all.

However, I realize that it's not enough to understand French texts. For example, I cannot understand the meaning of «à l'égard de» although I memorized the meanings of the words «à», «égard», «de». I wonder whether there is also a list of most commonly used phrases/expressions in the French language.

(Grammar is another issue, but via duolingo, I think that, at least, I glimpse the simplest grammars and for now, that's not the greatest obstruction.)

I searched on memrise and it seems to me that these lists are either too barren to cover the most common phrases, or too advanced, which is used by, maybe translators or those who are major in French. I'm looking for a good list, especially those which could easily be imported into Anki.

Merci beaucoup!

Related: [Oxford 3000 for French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/oxford-3000-for-french)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two fairly extensive lists, which I found by googling for "french idioms":

http://french.about.com/library/express/blexdico-a.htm
http://www.languagerealm.com/french/frenchidioms.php

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few links to pages with commonly used french phrases:

- this one is from Larousse.fr (dictionnary maker) and has various categories for commonly used phrases.
  http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/guide/anglais/
- this link shows common french idioms, with explanations and the origins of the idiom.
  http://lewebpedagogique.com/culturefrancaisepourtous/vie-quotidienne/les-expressions-courantes/

To address "a l'egard de", it has similar meaning as "en rapport a", "a propos de", "en ce qui concerne..."

*A l'egard de ta voiture...* -> Regarding your car...

*"A l'égard de celui qui vous prend votre femme, il n'est de pire vengeance que de la lui laisser." -Sacha Guitry*
"With respect to the man who steals your wife, there is no better revenge than to let him have her"

I hope this helps.